# Reading forms authentication ticket w/firefox and chrome

Tags: c#, firefox, authentication

I have 3 application that need single sign on. These are the web config sections I am using for authentication, authorization and the machine key settings. All the settings are the same in all 3 web applications. It works perfectly in Internet Explorer, but doesn't work at all in Firefox or Chrome. Is there anything else I need to do to get this work with Firefox and Chrome?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="2880" name="SSOCookie" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="true"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users ="?"/>
  <!--allow users ="*"/-->
</authorization>
<machineKey
    validationKey="2C02F632ABC3B809F0662B06EED7E985345504D93BB2893C3C8106F48A273054D4C29EDD63F34CF3E19C76AA8FCF12C28AC127A9C5D6DEFC139800B302CADBDC"
    decryptionKey="D7367948DC5AA193408CADB000E580A0FCCD71D8412D28E9AC76455FA85DB766"
    validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have to enable this in FireFox on each client

- Open Firefox and navigate to about:config
- Type “ntlm” in the filter field
- double click on network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris
- enter a comma and space separated list of urls that you want NTLM to be enabled for

for more details check out http://sivel.net/2007/05/firefox-ntlm-sso/

it seems that Chrome does not support NTLM
http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs

however, the user should be able to enter her credentials once and have them saved.

Comment: actually it turns out the issue was the fact that my three application were under different domains. Once I put all three in the same domain, it worked fine. Thanks for the reply though!